# UbuntuOne blocked by Norton Safe web

Tags: ubuntu-one

Are you aware that Norton Safe Web blocks access to files published on UbuntuOne? 
Reason given is they found a malicious worm uploaded (to a stated URL). 
We send "community" feedback explaining we think their blocking is not right. They do not block hotmail, gmail or Yahoo because some user send an infected mail? 
Might need follow-up from your site though.

Comment: You might want to tell Canonical about it; we're for the most part just users here.

Comment: I reported it using the contact us webform on ubuntuone.com.  I'll let you know the response.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something Canonical needs to deal with.  Perhaps emailing the Canonical people would help?  Because they'd need to address the issue, since most of the people here who answer are just users, and not the Canonical people.

Comment: Threat Report

Total threats found: 1

Small-whitebg-red  Viruses (what's this?)

Threats found: 1
Here is a complete list: (for more information about a specific threat, click on the Threat Name below)
Threat Name:  Trojan.Gen
Location:  http://ubuntuone.com/p/eBD/

Comment: Sorry, that was the report we got. Meanwhile anyone wanting to download a form from us gets a big red X.

Comment: what virus scanner you using?  Lots of virus scanners tend to screw up in their detection protocols.  Like one game that's a fan game made in Visual Basic returns "Trojan.General" or similar on Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE).  ***EDIT*** http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/sitereports/domain/ubuntuone.com  <--- AVG's reports of ubuntuone.com (reports as free of such malware)